# The ImageMagick option `trim:edges` has no effect

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am converting PDF files into JPEG pictures using the following ImageMagick command:

```
$ convert -density 300 -background white -alpha remove inputs/input.pdf -quality 100 -define trim:edges=west,east -trim outputs/output-%d.jpg
```

but it always trims all the edges regardless of what's defined in `-define trim:edges`.

Is there anything wrong with my command?

Comment: Have you tried `-fuzz 10%` or similar to allow small differences?

Comment: Yes (from 0 to 90%), but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried creating a very simple PNG image with a border or different coloured sides to see if it works how you imagine on that, e.g. `magick -size 200x100 xc:red -bordercolor blue -border 50 sample.png`

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version? It could be a version before that option was added.

Comment: @fmw42 here is the version I'm currently using: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't try that yet. I'll give it a shot and post my results here.

Comment: The define for trim:edges is only applicable in IM 7. It was not back ported to IM 6.  I just tested and it works on 7.1.0-57, but not 6.9.12-72

Comment: Thanks for that @fmw42, I'll upgrade to 7.1 then.

Comment: Be sure to use "magick" not "convert" with IM 7.  Or make a symbolic link between them.